# How can i count the number of errors on Form?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-validation

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FeS4A/78/)

How can i count the number of errors made on form ?

HTML

```
 <div ng-show="form.$submitted && form.$invalid">
      Sorry but 3 errors have been made.
 </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way you could do this by using the specific count of a specific error criteria, `required`, `pattern` etc.. that are available as a part of form's `$error[prop]` array. In your case you could try using `form.$error.required.length`:-

```
<div ng-show="form.$submitted && form.$invalid">
       Sorry but {{form.$error.required.length}} errors have been made.
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zw6mj2sb/)**

You could add a function on the controller which can determine the number of errors on the form and return it, and use it in the view to display the total error count.

```
 $scope.numberoferrors=function(form){
    var count = 0,
        errors = form.$error;

     angular.forEach(errors, function(val){ if(angular.isArray(val)) {  count += val.length; }  });
    //Object.keys(errors).forEach(function(key){ count += errors[key].length  }); //get count of all error categories from form

    return count;
 };
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3dendec9/)**